# python regular expression repeating pattern match

Tags: python, regex

I would like some thoughts on how to write a regular expression which validates a pattern

ex. `.??2`

one of more characters followed by two question marks followed by one or more numbers and if only if there is another repeating pattern then the seperator will be a semi colon.

more examples

`--??9;.??50;,??3` - in this example I have the pattern repeating and that is why the semi colon

or

`*??5` - a `*` followed by two qnestions marks followed by a number and no semi colon as there are no repeating groups

This is what i currently have

`.+\?\?\d+(;|)+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic pattern is `.+?\?\?\d+`. We have made the first `.+` non-greedy so it won't try to match the whole string right away. Use a repeated group to capture the subsequent patterns: `r'(.+?\?\?\d+)(;.+?\?\?\d+)*'`

Comment: import re
num = ".??1000;"
if re.search(r'(.+?\?\?\d+)(;.+?\?\?\d+)+',num):
print "pass" 
else: print "fail"

prints fail- but it should pass

Comment: Ha, good point. Fixed regex to use `*` instead of `+` on the repeated subsequence.

Comment: so you say this is correct
r'(.+?\?\?\d+)(;.+?\?\?\d+)*' 
then num = ".??1000;." 
prints pass when it should fail

Comment: But that does pass...you're using `re.search` which doesn't try to match the whole string, so it matches just the first 7 characters. If you want to anchor at both ends, put `^` at the start and `$` at the end.